# Is there a legal path for overturning Nixon vs US (not to be confused with US v Nixon)?

Tags: civil-procedure, us-supreme-court

[Nixon v US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nixon_v._United_States) established that impeachment is not [justiciable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justiciability).  However, this provides a path for it to become a carte blanche unrestrained power of Congress.  This is a far cry from its intended aim of being a power which would only be exercised with a great self-restraint by Congress.

Can this decision reach the SCOTUS only via a case brought by another impeached party?  Or is there another legal path for SCOTUS to consider it again?  Is there a path through an injunction?  I am not asking what would guarantee its overturn.  I am only asking about how the legal system works to make it possible (if a plaintiff succeeds in all challenges which they bring).

Answer (score 3):

While this does not really directly answer your question of overturn, but this might somewhat directly address your original concern.

> This provides a path for it to become a carte blanche unrestrained power of Congress.

This statement seems a bit misleading. It seems to indicate that Congress now is unfettered to abuse its impeachment power, but this is not true, because Congress is divided into two halves that place check on each other:

> The House of Representatives ... shall have the sole Power of Impeachment.
>
> The Senate shall have the sole Power to try all Impeachments.

Answer (score 1):

> Can this decision reach the SCOTUS only via a case brought by another impeached party?

Yes. A case may only be brought by someone who has suffered or will suffer an actual injury.  The courts have established that a citizen's interest in the constitutionally correct functioning of the government is insufficient.

> Or is there another legal path for SCOTUS to consider it again?

No.

> Is there a path through an injunction?

Who would issue such an injunction?  What act would it enjoin?

The court is very unlikely to take such a case.

Comment: it could enjoin an impeachment hearing. or an impeachment trial before the trial starts, but after the impeachment has been voted on.  I am not saying it's possible.  I am asking if there is a legal path for it.  Please, refrain from commenting on what is "likely".  This muddies the issue.  I was not asking if any such challenge would succeed or would be likely to succeed.  This is a question about what is *procedurally* possible.

Comment: But an injunction is a remedy.  That's a separate question from whether the court can revisit the previous ruling or the circumstances under which it can do so.

Comment: wouldn't the court have to overturn the previous ruling before it can consider an injunction?

Comment: Yes.  But the question appears to be about whether it's possible to overturn the prior decision, until at the end it asks about what happens *after* the decision is overturned.  It's like you're asking for directions to the supermarket and all of a sudden you say "could I buy milk there?"  It's a different question.

Comment: not at all.  the question does not (at all) ask about what would happen after a decision was overturned.  it asks about possible ways of reaching a destination.  it prefaces it by saying that there are possible reasons for going to that destination.